# I am getting an error value not found in databricks

Tags: databricks

I am new to DataBricks. I have following code in scala the adds a new column to existing dataframe it checks for a specific column value and if it is `null` assigns `0` otherwise `1`.

```
val sv_string = "select * from temp_tbl_ASBReports r left join temp_tbl_ASBInvestigations i on r.nh_parentasbcase = i.nh_asbcaseid"

val df_asbreportssv = spark.sql(sv_string)

df_asbreportssv.withColumn("InInvestigation",when((df_asbreportssv("nh_parentasbcase").isNull), "0").otherwise("1"))
```

It throws the following error:

```
error: not found: value when
    df_asbreportssv.withColumn("InInvestigation",when((df_asbreportssv("nh_parentasbcase").isNull), "1").otherwise("0"))
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Have you imported the when function? E.g. ```import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ ```

Comment: No I haven't.Will try and come back.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I was assuming the Databricks it is implicit import and didn't not realise I have explicitly import it. It resolved the error but does not add the column. I am trying to troubleshoot it.

Comment: This is resolved now thanks!

Comment: @user13033419 Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing the answer as per the comment by @Daniel and Original Poster @user13033419 has confirmed as the issue has been resolved.

---

You need to use "**import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._**" before the code.

**Example:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(2, 3, 4).toDF("number")

df
  .withColumn("number_factorial", factorial(col("number")))
  .show()
```

Modify your code accordingly:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sv_string = "select * from temp_tbl_ASBReports r left join temp_tbl_ASBInvestigations i on r.nh_parentasbcase = i.nh_asbcaseid"

val df_asbreportssv = spark.sql(sv_string)

df_asbreportssv.withColumn("InInvestigation",when((df_asbreportssv("nh_parentasbcase").isNull), "0").otherwise("1"))
```

---